# Running pip command via via proxy does not work

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, pip

The proxy address inside corporate is as follows: http://proxy-europe.network.CorporateName.com/, As googled and explored on stackovetrflow, a way around the proxy when running `pip` is to use

```
pip install --proxy=https://proxy-europe.network.CorporateName.com pandas
```

but it is not working for me:

```
C:\Users\3626416>pip install --proxy=http://proxy-europe.network.CorporateName.com pandas
Collecting pandas
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 301 Moved Permanently'))': /simple/pandas/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 301 Moved Permanently'))': /simple/pandas/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 301 Moved Permanently'))': /simple/pandas/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 301 Moved Permanently'))': /simple/pandas/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 301 Moved Permanently'))': /simple/pandas/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas
```

Any advice as to what I am doing wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: I guess `https` might be important which is lacking in the actual command you ran

Comment: I tried pip install --proxy=https://proxy-europe.network.CorporateName.com pandas but got the same error. Could it be that even company has blocked these activities?

Comment: This is a question best directed to your IT department. Random ppl on the internet do not know how your company network is set up

Comment: I did open a IT ticket .. lets see